# Is it possible to simulate a sequence of taps in a flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, touch

I need to build a flutter app to simulate taps.

For example: Imagine a keyboard numbers app with a button underneath called "Simulate sequence button".
So, what I need to do is:

- To tap the simulate button;
- This button is responsible to simulate a sequence of taps on the keyboard numbers;
- Display the tapped numbers on the screen.

Is it possible? How do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by this? ... `simulate a sequence of taps`

Comment: I mean that I need to simulate more than one tap.
Ex: simulate press key 1, than key 2, than key 3. Resulting 123

Comment: i am sorry that i was not clear ... i know what `sequence` means ... what do you mean by `simulate`?

Comment: No problem. This means that I want to press just one button, and the result will be as if I had pressed several buttons

Answer (score -1):

You can "simulate" UI interactions (like taps, swipes etc.) from integration tests only ([about integration tests on flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/integration-tests)).

For real running application you can just use `onPressed` button handler that adds needed text to label or text field:

```dart
class _SomeState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextField(controller: textController),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          textController.text += '123';
        },
        child: Text('Button')
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The result that I need is not just concat a text (I need to "simulate" a button press). Do you have any other idea what to do if I need to "simulate" a button press?

Comment: Sorry, may be my answer is not clear. `You can "simulate" UI interactions from integration tests only` means that you can not do it in common runtime.

Comment: Why text concatenation function not suitable for you? Can you please explain this?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Is because I need to simulate the actual button press, not just the result.
I will try to be clear with another example: 
Imagine two different apps, so I press the button on app 1 -> opens the second app -> simulates pressing the button on app 2 (without tapping app 2)

Was I clear? Thanks!

Comment: Example is clear, thanks. But I still don't see any reason to simulate button taps. In your example you can use deep link, parse parameters and call needed function without UI interaction simulations.